# Capture user input and actions with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

Is it possible to capture user input/actions with Selenium WebDriver, in the same way that you can use the Selenium IDE for recording / creating tests?

i.e. when the user enters a URL, clicks a link, fills in a text box, clicks a button etc etc.

I'd like to be able to capture these actions using the WebDriver rather than just using the Selenium IDE, as I want to integrate with other classes available in my Java application.

Comment: + favorites. In other news: I am not aware of this being possible

Comment: You can only change the format in Selenium IDE during recording. By default, it is recorded in HTML format. You can change the format for java as Java / JUnit4 / WebDriver which will record in Java format for you.

Answer (score 4):

I attempted to offer a viable solution in [Record Actions using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880561/record-actions-using-selenium)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'record' a set of actions with Selenium WebDriver, you will need to write those steps manually.

Strictly speaking you can capture user input by using the WebDriver API in your chosen language (`C#, Java, PHP, Ruby. Python, Perl or JavaScript`) and it vaguely resembles using the DOM.  If it suits your requirements you could use configuration files to supply some of your user input.

**Navigate to a URL:**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get('url')
```

**Click a link/button:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("coolestWidgetEvah"));

element.click();
```

**Enter Text in a field:**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("coolestWidgetEvah"));

element.sendKeys('userinput');
```

For more information on the API Selenium HQ is pretty definitive:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

If you're going from `Selenium IDE` to writing tests it'd be really useful to check out the page object pattern as I've found it makes your tests more maintainable in the long-run.  This link is a good starting point because it gives an overview, and a visual representation of what you get by following the pattern:

http://blog.josephwilk.net/cucumber/page-object-pattern.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: The requirement in question is something different. Requirement is to emulate recording as part of application itself as the application is running

Comment: I see, as far as I know you can't just record your actions like you can with Selenium IDE.

Comment: The answer is not matched according to the question

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't an easy way to do it - but recording on IDE and exporting as a java file has worked well for me (File -> Export test case as...). I usually do it to c# but have used it with java.